# .htaccess RewriteRule: two domains using same server and directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multiple-domains

As a bit of background, we have two domains:

1. **mydomain.com**
2. **mydomain.cz**

**mydomain.cz** points to **mydomain.com**'s server and uses the same directory. We have a RewriteRule in .htaccess (which both domains share) as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ project.php?id=$1 [NC,L] # Handle project requests
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ project_cz.php?id=$1 [NC,L] # Handle project requests
```

This RewriteRule shows **mydomain.com/1** while using content from **mydomain.com/project.php?id=1** (for example) and **mydomain.cz/1** also pulls **mydomain.com/project.php?id=1** for content. However, I would like any **mydomain.cz/(insert id here)'s** to pull content from **project_cz.php?id=(insert id here)** rather than displaying the server's domain, mydomain.com - any ideas?

For example: **mydomain.cz/1** would use **mydomain.com/project_cz.php?id=1** and **mydomain.com/1** would use **mydomain.com/project.php?id=1**

Many thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a [RewriteCond](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond) directive, which defines the conditions for the *following* [RewriteRule](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteRule).

**So for example:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ project.php?id=$1 [NC,L] # Handle project requests

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.cz
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ project_cz.php?id=$1 [NC,L] # Handle project requests
```

Comment: Wow! The speed of responses never fails to amaze me on here. And a perfect piece of code as always - great work, many thanks!