# htaccess rewrite based on hostname or domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two different domains (let's say www.site1.com and www.site2.com) that point to the same hosting server.

I need the two different domain names because I want to use the first one for the italian contents and the second one for the english contents. The contents are the same, unless for the language, but the domains *have* to be different.

So, I'd like to write a rule that lets me translate from:

- `www.site1.com` to `/?lang=it`
- `www.site2.com` to `/?lang=en`

I usually use the same domain name for many different languages rewriting from `www.site.com/it/` to `/?lang=it` (of course, a transparent rewriting - the user doesn't see any different URL).

I'd like to achieve the same using different domains but I can't figure out how... I've been working on it for hours and I can't achieve what I want!

Usually I use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-z]{2})
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})[/]*$ /index.php?lang=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

I can't get this one work, to use different domains:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site1\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php?lang=it
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?lang=it [NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site2\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php?lang=en
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?lang=en [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess RewriteRule: two domains using same server and directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972413/htaccess-rewriterule-two-domains-using-same-server-and-directory)

Comment: What happens with this setup? And if you remove the second RewriteCond (`^/index.php?lang=it` should never match, REQUEST_URI does not expose the query parameters, check %{QUERY_STRING} instead) ?

Comment: I have tried many many different "versions" of the rules in the latter grey block... I always get an HTTP 500 error or just an empty $_GET. I mean, among the others tentatives, with or without the second condition "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php?lang=it".

Comment: Thank you Lawrence Cherone! That one works like a charm!

Comment: One should not forget the `RewriteEngine on` above the other rules...;)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Lawrence Cherone - Thank you, that one works like a charm! Now it works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site1\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?lang=it [NC,QSA] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site2\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?lang=en [NC,QSA]
```

Of course I check the www redirect before this rule.

Thank you!!