# .htaccess URL RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this URL: **http://www.my-domain.com/v/index.php?vid=euOUq6Sr-iujkdDzsw4s_uSX59Lhn2qqA=z15**
I want to rewrite it to: **http://v.my-domain.com/euOUq6Sr-iujkdDzsw4s_uSX59Lhn2qqA=z15**

Note that: 
v -> which is folder name becomes at the beginning 
AND 
index.php?vid= -> hide

Answer (score 0):

Here's some new code based on the updated information.  This worked in my testing environment.

```
    RewriteBase /v/
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my-domain\.com$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^vid=(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(index.php)?$ http://v.my-domain.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

There are still a few assumptions, so you may need to tweak it a bit if there are edge cases you didn't mention.  For example, this snippet:

1. Requires the query string to always be present
2. Expects no other query variable but vid to be present
3. Actually doing a redirect instead of rewrite - you can take out the R=301, to change that.

**Sources:**

1. [Subfolder to Subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/567476/permanently-redirect-subfolder-blog-to-subdomain-on-another-server)
2. [Query Strings in Rewrites](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString)
3. [Domain Name in Rewrites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232722/htaccess-rewrite-based-on-hostname-or-domain-name)

Comment: Thank you but it does not work for me. There is something I did not mention it which is : the .htaccess file will be inside the folder (v) and one more thing my website is running using WordPress so there is another .htaccess which is used for wordpress and because of that I will put it inside the (v) folder so the codes will be applied on this folder only

Comment: @Kaito-Kaito that does change things a bit.  I have a rough idea of how to modify the rules; I'll replicate that situation on my server and update my answer as soon as I have some time.  Meanwhile, you may want to edit your question and add those details for anyone else that may choose to answer.

Comment: @Kaito-Kaito I've updated my answer based on the above information