# htaccess rewrite based on domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

my project has multiple domains and I would like to redirect 100 pages for 1 of these domain.
Now I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232722/htaccess-rewrite-based-on-hostname-or-domain-name) on how to set up conditions for 1 domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site1\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?lang=it [NC,QSA] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site2\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?lang=en [NC,QSA]
```

My question would be, how can I set this up for 100 pages?
Do I have to duplicate the condition for each link?

What I want to do is this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site1\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^some   https://www.mypage.de/shop/some [R=301, L]
RewriteRule ^page   https://www.mypage.de/shop/page [R=301, L]
RewriteRule ^settings   https://www.mypage.de/shop/settings [R=301, L]
```

Comment: Are there, aside of the 100 specific pages, other pages that shouldn't be redirected?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden yes there are

Comment: you should specify which number of pages is big , then make a condition according to that

Answer (score 2):

There are so many scenarios to do in this case , for example , you could redirect every page except specific page like this :

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site1\.com [NC] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(page1|page2|page3|whatever)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$   https://www.mypage.de/shop/$1 [R=301, L]
```

But , if the number of page who should be excluded is large , you could create directory , for example , `new` then move all files that have to be redirected at it , then make this rule

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site1\.com [NC] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/new%{REQUEST_URI}  -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new/$1 [L]
```

Then you could add this to redirect any URI contains `new` to that new location :

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site1\.com [NC] 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/new/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$   https://www.mypage.de/shop/$1 [R=301, L]
```

So code should look like this :

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site1\.com [NC] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/new%{REQUEST_URI}  -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new/$1 [L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site1\.com [NC] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/new/
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$   https://www.mypage.de/shop/$1 [R=301, L]
```

Comment: This is so far the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mypage.de/shop/$1 [QSA]
```

This will redirect every single page.

If you only want 100 specific pages you must add one by one. Like other answers were provided.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure if this would work only for one domain or for all. But anyway I need to be able to redirect these 100 specific pages and not all pages.

Comment: Your regex doesn't make sense. `([^/d]+)/` -> every character except the character `d`.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden you're right. sorry it's still morning .. answer updated. Remove your -1 please :)

Comment: Yes, you updated, but still the answer is not what the OP is looking for. This will redirect every page, OP asks for 100 specific pages.

Comment: OP mentioned in the comments that there were more than 100 pages. Which wasn't included in the main question. Nothing that I could figure out when I first wrote the answer. @RonvanderHeijden

Answer (score 0):

Probably **Skip flag** will be the best aproach.

It looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule  .?  -  [S=100]
RewriteRule ^some   https://www.mypage.de/shop/some [R=301, L]
RewriteRule ^page   https://www.mypage.de/shop/page [R=301, L]
RewriteRule ^settings   https://www.mypage.de/shop/settings [R=301, L]
.....
RewriteRule ^rule_for_100nd_page   https://www.mypage.de/shop/settings [R=301, L]
```

How this works.

1. Test HOST if NOT skip 100 (S=100) the next RewriteRules if YES `RewriteRule  .?  -  [S=100]` is ignored
2. Write your 100 rules for `www.site1.com` source domain and go on.

Comment: and... Is this it ?

Comment: Show your .htacces / part of this. May be I can help.

Comment: It  fine. I posted my solution and it works fine. I was just hoping to avoid the extra line but it doesn't matter. Thx for the help

Comment: Probably you miss `!` (exclamation sing befor domain name) S[kip] in this case works with negation. It means if HOST is NOT in checked domain do S=100 (or other number) if does - S=100 is ignored and process next rules  [for domain www.site1.com]- in this way you have only on test per domain name for any you want rewriterules.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your page names are same after redirect as you've shown in your question, you can use a single rule like this as your top most rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site1\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .+ https://www.mypage.de/shop/$0 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for your testing.

Comment: the answer is not what the OP is looking for. This will redirect every page, OP asks for 100 specific pages.

Comment: This for question title that says **htaccess rewrite based on domain** also do read assumption at the start of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So after testing some of the suggestions I ended up having to add the condition to each rule in order to make it work.

So as far as I can tell you can't set conditions for more than one rule if the targets are to specific.

So my solution for this issue looks like this.
Thanks for all the suggestions.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site1\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^some   https://www.site1.de/shop/some [R=301, L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site1\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^page   https://www.site1.de/random/page [R=301, L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site1\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^settings   https://www.site1.de/whatever/settings [R=301, L]
```