# Apache - How to write a rule based on URL we access the site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

we have 2 Urls pointing to same apache instance. One URL, for Admin and other for client's. When accessing admin URL, should allow /admin where as /admin should be denied while accessing through client URL. Could you help with sample apache rewrite rules.

```
https://example-admin.com/admin - Admins allowed to access admin url
https://example-client.com/admin - Client should not allowed to access admin url
https://example-client.com/client - Client allowed to access client site
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried this below to block admin context path for client URL. But this isn't working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/auth/admin(/.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried .htaccess rules in your question as your efforts, thank you.

Comment: No, I didn't say about tags. Please do add your tried code/.htaccess rules which you tried in your question, thank you.

Comment: Haven't find solution yet.

Comment: Whatever you tried from Google OR from documentation please do add there is nothing right or wrong in terms of efforts, as we all are here to learn its highly encouraged for questioners to have efforts in question, thank you.

Comment: How to check the requested host name using a RewriteCond: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10232722/1427878 Denying access when the condition is met, can be done by the RewriteRule substitution being just `-`, and using the `F` flag to give a 403 Forbidden response.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. I tried this below to block admin context path for client URL. But this isn't working
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/auth/admin(/.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/auth/admin(/.*)? [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ - [F]
> ```

Where did `/auth` come from? It's not in your example URLs. However, you need to check the requested hostname, since you only want to block paths that start `/admin` when accessed from the `example-client.com` host. In other words, you need to check the value of the `Host` HTTP request header, which is available in the `HTTP_HOST` server variable.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example-client\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin($|/) - [F]
```

And this needs to go near the top of your root `.htaccess` file.

You don't need a separate condition (`RewriteCond` directive) to check the requested URL-path, as this can be checked (more efficiently) in the `RewriteRule` directive itself.