# How to prevent this .htaccess redirect rule affecting subdomains

Tags: .htaccess

How do I prevent this .htaccess redirect rule in the root from affecting any subdomains?

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I've tried adding `Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks` per answer to similar q's to no avail.

I also had partial success with `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ https://domain.co.uk/$1.php [NC,L]` but without the correct condition this still didn't work.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Add a RewriteCond that checks the host name of the request. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10241757/1427878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @CBroe's comment the correctly implemented code is as below:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```