# htaccess partial domain to domain redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I’m working for a client who has requested to change a massive amount of urls, around 500, and then have redirects from old to new. Basically going from:

online.XXX.com/XXX

To

example.com/estore/XXX

I’m concerned that this will create a time lag on the page load. Every time a url is requested the server has to do a look up through everyone of these redirects to check if it needs to send the traffic elsewhere.

Would it not be possible to use a more ‘compact’ rule and redirect the domains? Something like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/estore/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Would this work? This would then be a catch all for every older url.

However would this rule then try and force the non e-commerce pages to the /estore/ url? How do I change the catch all (.*) to only include the online.XXX.com/ urls?

Thanks

Comment: _"How do I change the catch all (.*) to only include the online.XXX.com/ urls?"_ - RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only. You need to put a RewriteCond before the rule, that checks on the host name.

Comment: CBroe, thanks for the reply, could you provide an example fo the RewriteCond rule?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10232722/1427878