# Redirecting old domain urls from old host, to new domain urls with new host, but individual pages are named differently

Tags: redirect, dns, hosting

Both domains were purchased through network solutions. The old host won't exist anymore, so I can't rely on them to serve the htaccess redirects. I can point the nameservers to the new host, but then what? None of my redirect code seems to be working. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Ex: 
olddomain.com > newdomain.com
olddomain.com/hello > newdomain.com/goodbye
olddomain.com/123 > newdomain.com/456
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something similar to this: [.htaccess RewriteRule: two domains using same server and directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972413/htaccess-rewriterule-two-domains-using-same-server-and-directory)

Having that said, in most cases a static html page saying "This page has moved. Link to new page: ..." is preferred above .htaccess redirects, because people browsing your webpage will then update their bookmarks to the new URL, which they will not otherwise.